# Ignoring persistence.xml -> EntityManager is null

Tags: java, maven, persistence, code-injection, entitymanager

when I try to inject the EntityManager, it is always null without throwing an exception.
It doesn't matter where the persistence.xml is placed, if it is empty or missing; this file seems completly to be ignored.
My persistence.xml is placed in src/main/resources/META-INF/.
I try to get it run in a Jetty now for 2 days, but there is no way. I would really appreciate your help.

My producer:

```
@Singleton
public class ApplicationResources {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emManagerFactory;

    @Produces
    public EntityManagerFactory produces() {
        System.err.println("produces " + emManagerFactory);
        return emManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

My DAO

```
@Stateless
public class AverageCountryPricesDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManagerFactory emManagerFactory;


    public AverageCountryPricesDAO() {
        System.err.println("construct DAO");
    }

    public void testit() {
        System.err.println("emManagerFactory: " + emManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- weld-servlet JAR is manually removed from WAR file -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.7.v20120910</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.7.v20120910</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Put the name of your persistence unit as an attribute of the @PersistenceUnit annotation. http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/PersistenceUnit

Comment: Hi onesixtyfourth, unfortunately I already tried to do this ... changing nothing :(

Comment: How about using EntityManager instead of the factory?

Comment: Same, makes no difference

Comment: FYI: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dieselPriceMapPU").createEntityManager();` works fine